# How to customise a template

Tags: xcode, templates, xcode-template

I have a very specific question so I hope someone here can answer. I have been working on making my own templates on Xcode and objective C so that I can start my projects a bit faster for iOS. Thanks to people in this forum and also mostly this:http://www.telerik.com/blogs/how-to-create-custom-project-templates-in-xcode-7 really good article, I have managed to create my own template with a view controller. The only thing missing is the #import "ViewController.h" in the AppDelegate.h file. Granted, it's not a huge effort to write it myself, but it would be nice to finish the job. I know it's something that I must add to the XML info.plist file, but I am not too sure what, so any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.